# Mongodb dump (filtering documents and fields)

Tags: mongodb, filter, dump, bson, mongoexport

I want to make a *partial* dump of a Mongodb database (*partial* as in, I need to filter some **documents** and some **fields**). Then, this dump will be imported onto another server.

I cannot use the *mongodump* utility, as it doesn't allow filtering fields.
I could use the *mongoexport* utility, as it allows filtering both documents and fields. Though, the documentation states that *mongoexport* can only output a JSON file and:

> does not reliably preserve all rich BSON data types, because JSON can only represent a subset of the types supported by BSON.

1. I find this statement a bit vague, and I don't entirely understand it. So, what happens exactly if I dump my database in JSON? What risks do I run? Do I risk losing some documents?
2. If you think I should absolutely avoid using *mongoexport* in production, can I write my own Nodejs application to do the filtering and to output a dump in BSON? Or would that not be possible?

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to do using [Views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) without resorting to writing a low level implementation reading and writing the BSON content. There are also options which do in fact *preserve type* even when using JSON formats, and you don't even need a "View" for that.

### Using Views with `mongodump`

The basic premise is to create a View which only returns the content you want. A View can be the result of any aggregation pipeline expression.

For example, given a simple document in a collection:

```
db.test.insert({ "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 })
```

You can create the View on that collection, with just wanted fields:

```
db.test.createView("testView", "test", [{ "$project": { "a": 1, "b": 2 } }])
```

Then exiting the mongo shell you can access the View from [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) using the [`--viewsAsCollections`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-viewsascollections) option:

```
mongodump --db test --collection testView --viewsAsCollections
```

This exports just the named *"collection"* ( actually a View ) only. The [`--viewsAsCollections`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-viewsascollections) means that instead of [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) just returning the view definition ( being essentially the aggregation pipeline ) it returns the results instead just like it was a real collection.

The resulting BSON content can then be loaded via [`mongorestore`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/):

```
mongorestore --db other --collection test
```

Then the content from the BSON dump is actually written into the new database target of the host you are connecting to and with the specified collection name

```
use other
db.test.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bfb3e0eadd1d8af906ad140"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
```

Noting also that as a [View](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/), the aggregation pipeline can really be anything, so `$match` statements can filter and you can transform or even actually "aggregate" however you want.

### Using Views or `--fields` with `mongoexport`

In much the same way, the [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) utility can also access the content from a View.

Despite this not being *"strict BSON"*, there is actually a standard with MongoDB which does in fact *preserve* the data types. This is actually covered in the documentation under [MongoDB extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

So this is NOT a Binary format, and as JSON it does take considerably more storage space but the necessary information is indeed there.

For example:

```
db.mixed.insert({
  "a": NumberLong(1),
  "b": NumberDecimal("123.45"),
  "c": new Date(),
  "d":  "unwanted"
})
```

Which would appear in the `mongo` shell as:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5bfb428790b2b4e4241a015c"),
        "a" : NumberLong(1),
        "b" : NumberDecimal("123.45"),
        "c" : ISODate("2018-11-26T00:47:03.033Z"),
        "d" : "unwanted"
}
```

You can still set up a View:

```
db.createView("mixedView", "mixed", [{ "$project": { "a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1 } }])
```

And the export will just pick up the data:

```
mongoexport --db test --collection mixedView > out.json

{
        "_id": {
                "$oid": "5bfb428790b2b4e4241a015c"
        },
        "a": {
                "$numberLong": "1"
        },
        "b": {
                "$numberDecimal": "123.45"
        },
        "c": {
                "$date": "2018-11-26T00:47:03.033Z"
        }
}
```

Or the same thing on the original collection, just using [`--fields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-fields) for selection:

```
mongoexport --db test --collection mixed --fields a,b,c > out.json
```

With exactly the same output. Being that the only restriction is the [`--query`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-query) can only support a regular query expression as given to `find()` or similar. This is not as flexible as a [View](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/), but can do rudimentary filtering for most needs.

The [Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format is recognized by [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) and there are also implementations of parsers available for many languages which recognize this as well, and as the content is read it is inserted into the target collection with the *"type"* information preserved:

```
mongoimport --db other --collection mixed out.json
```

And then viewing the data:

```
use other
db.mixed.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5bfb428790b2b4e4241a015c"),
        "a" : NumberLong(1),
        "b" : NumberDecimal("123.45"),
        "c" : ISODate("2018-11-26T00:47:03.033Z")
}
```

So it is possible and the [Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format exists for the purpose of data interchange in situations where sending *binary* content may not be viable or even desirable, but maintaining the *"type"* information *is desirable*.

---

Overall there are many options you can use without needing to revert to reading and writing binary BSON formats, or any other complex binary format to store the data in between transfers.

As a note on the *"vague"* passage, the actual supported BSON types are listed within the [Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) page of the documentation. You can even compare this to the [BSON Specification](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) to see that despite the *"cautious"* statement the *common* types of data you will indeed use are actually all supported there. Whilst *some* external interpretations of that spec may not adhere to understanding *ALL* of them, the utilities bundled such as `mongoexport` and `mongoimport` are indeed compliant.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. So, correct me if I'm wrong, but the answer to my first question is that no, I don't lose any information by using JSON, because as you said "*this is NOT a Binary format, and as JSON it does take considerably more storage space but the necessary information is indeed there*".  

This means that a JSON dump file holds exactly the same information but it encodes it by taking up more space. So I can just expect a JSON dump file to be larger than its BSON equivalent dump file, right?

Comment: As for my second question: is it possible to write my own Nodejs application to do the filtering and to output a dump file in BSON?

Comment: For now I'll use your solution (that is, creaing a view and then dumping it with *mongodump*), but I'm still interested in knowing whether I could use a custom Nodejs application instead. The reason for this is that performance is important in my scenario, and I have a feeling that creating a view and subsequently dumping it with *mongodump* would take significantly longer than the execution of a Nodejs application that filters data and automatically writes it into a (BSON) dump file.